# array of vectors of OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I have created vector of vectors to store cv::Mat (framecollection). My plan is to take each frame of a video then partitioned into N*N blocks and store. But here while I am running the code, it stored only the last frame every location of framecollection. I don't know what is the problem with the code.

```
int nframes=(int)capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
int frame_row=capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
int frame_cols=capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
int X=ceil(frame_row/(double)N);//rows
int Y=ceil(frame_cols/(double)N);//cols 
std::vector<std::vector<Mat> > framecollection(nframes, std::vector<Mat> (X*Y));
//std::array< std::vector<Mat>, nframes > framecollection;
int f=0;
for( ; ; )
{
    capture >> frame;

    if(frame.empty())
        break;

    vector<Mat> blocks;
    for (int r = 0; r < frame_row; r += N)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < frame_cols; c += N)
        {
            Mat tile = frame(Range(r, min(r + N, frame_row)),Range(c, min(c + N, frame_cols)));
            blocks.push_back(tile);
        }
    }
    framecollection[f]=blocks;
    f++;

}
```

//framecollection giving only last frame in every locations

Comment: try `blocks.push_back(tile.clone());`

Comment: `VideoCapture` reuses the `Mat` that stores the frame. `Mat` works somewhat like a shared pointer (you should probably spend more time reading the documentation) -- it only copies/reallocates when necessary or explicitly requested. In your case you're just making additional views to the single underlying shared image.

Comment: Thank you sturkmen and Dan Mašek for the response, I understood my mistake.